# Convert an ASCII art table to a UTF-8 table

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

When I write documentation, comments, etc. I love making ASCII tables. They usually end up looking pretty good, but I always feel that they could look even better - especially since UTF-8/Unicode includes the [box drawing characters](https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/box-drawing/). However, these characters are very burdensome to use, requiring several key presses to insert. Your task? Write a program or a function that can automatically convert ASCII tables to the UTF-8/Unicode equivalent.

This challenge was [sandboxed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16972).

### Challenge

Write a program, that given an ASCII table as an input string, outputs the table redrawn with the Unicode/UTF-8 box drawing characters. Specifically, the characters that are a part of the table should be translated as follows:

```
(Unicode, 3 bytes each in UTF-8)
- to ─ (\u2500)
| to │ (\u2502)
= to ═ (\u2550)

and + to one of:
   ┌ (\u250C), ┐ (\u2510), └ (\u2514), ┘ (\u2518),
   ├ (\u251C), ┤ (\u2524), ┬ (\u252C), ┴ (\u2534),
   ┼ (\u253C)
or, if '=' on either side:
   ╒ (\u2552), ╕ (\u2555), ╘ (\u2558), ╛ (\u255D),
   ╞ (\u255E), ╡ (\u2561), ╤ (\u2564), ╧ (\u2567),
   ╪ (\u256A)
```

### Details

**I/O:**

- [Default I/O](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447) is allowed
- You may take input in any reasonable format, including the table as a string, or a path to a file containing the table.
- You may output to a file and take the file name as an additional argument.

  - However, **you may not modify the input file**. (It should be retained for ease of future editing)

**Input:**

- You may assume that every row of input has been padded to be the same length with .
- You may not assume that the first character after a newline is a part of the table borders (as it may be whitespace).
- Input is considered a valid table if all characters (that are a part of the table) `-=|` are connected to exactly two characters and `+` are connected to at least one character both horizontally and vertically.
- Your program may not produce any errors with valid inputs.
- If the input is not valid the behavior is undefined and you may produce any output.
- The input may contain any UTF-8 characters, including the box drawing characters.

**Output:**

- Any of the characters `-=|+` that are not a part of the table **must** be left as-is.
- Similarly, any other characters must be left as-is.
- A single leading and/or trailing newline is allowed.

**Other:**

- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden, as per usual.
- If your preferred language has a built-in that solves this problem, you may not use it.

  - This means programs, functions, subroutines or instructions that would be valid submissions for this challenge with no additions.
- Each of the characters needed in this challenge are three bytes long when they're encoded in UTF-8.

**Connected characters**:

A character is connected to another, if:

- It is `|` and is directly above or below `+` or `|`;
- It is `-` and is directly before or after `+` or `-`;
- It is `=` and is directly before or after `+` or `=`;
- It is `+` and is directly above or below `|` or `+`, or is directly before or after `-`, `=` or `+`.

A character is considered a part of the table, if it is connected to any character that is a part of the table. By definition, the first `+` in the input is a part of the table.

### Examples

Examples available [here](https://pastebin.com/Wzcr113K) as a copy-pastable version.

```
 Input:                    Output:
+------------------+      ┌──────────────────┐
|   Hello+World!   |      │   Hello+World!   │
+==================+      ╞══════════════════╡
| This is+my first |  ->  │ This is+my first │
|+-+ code|golf  +-+|      │+-+ code|golf  +-+│
|+-+chall|enge! +-+|      │+-+chall|enge! +-+│
+------------------+      └──────────────────┘

     +===+===+===+             ╒═══╤═══╤═══╕
     | 1 | 2 | 3 |             │ 1 │ 2 │ 3 │
 +---+===+===+===+         ┌───╪═══╪═══╪═══╡
 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |         │ 1 │ 1 │ 2 │ 3 │
 +---+---+---+---+    ->   ├───┼───┼───┼───┤
 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 6 |         │ 2 │ 2 │ 4 │ 6 │
 +---+---+---+---+         ├───┼───┼───┼───┤
 |-3 |-3 |-6 |-9 |         │-3 │-3 │-6 │-9 │
 +===+---+---+---+         ╘═══╧───┴───┴───┘

      +-----+         ->      <Undefined>

      +-----+         ->      ┌─────┐
      +-----+                 └─────┘

+-----------------+
|  Hello, World!  |
| This is invalid |   ->      <Undefined>
|      input      |
 -----------------+

       ++++                      ┌┬┬┐
       ++++           ->         ├┼┼┤
       ++++                      └┴┴┘

       +--+
       ++++           ->      <Undefined>
       +--+
```

### Finally...

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the least amount of bytes wins. Happy golfing!

Comment: In the first example, why are the consecutive `+-+` excerpts not considered to form a connected table?

Comment: If a maybe 16-bit function use a single byte to represent ╡, how's the byte count?

Comment: @recursive If you mean the first `Hello World` table, the inner tables are not considered to form a table because the text inside the table must stay unchanged, and they are not considered a part of the outer table borders as they are not connected to them properly.

Comment: If you mean the first `+----+` example, it would be because the direction of the corners would be ambiguous.

Comment: Oh, the "no tables within tables unless they connect to extend the outermost possible table" requirement makes this a lot tougher.

Comment: ...although it is eased by "By definition, the first `+` in the input is a part of the table."

Comment: @l4m2 According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), these UTF-8 characters occupy 3 bytes of memory each. I'll add a mention of that.

Comment: @l4m2 The rule is "the byte count is the file size when the program is stored on disk". If it correctly outputs the table (on a 16-bit machine?) then it should be fine.

Comment: (this is ascii-art, it suffices if the output looks correct. right?)

Comment: Can the input contain any of the Unicode box drawing characters?

Comment: @RootTwo I'm going to go with *yes*, since both of the existing answers already handle them fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Python 3, <s>392</s> 281 bytes

Golfed it quite a bit more and converted to a recursive solution instead of an iterative one:

```
def h(a):
 def g(i):
  k=-3;d=a[i]=='=';z[i]=''
  for p,j,r in zip((1,2,4,8),(i+1,i+w,i-1,i-w),('+-=','+|')*2):
   if 0<=j<len(a)and{a[i],a[j]}<={*r}:k+=p;d|=a[j]=='=';z[j]and g(j)
  z[i]="┌╒!!─═┐╕┬╤@@└╘││├╞┘╛┴╧┤╡┼╪"[2*k+d]
 w=a.find('\n')+1;z=[*a];g(a.find('+'))
 return''.join(z)
```

Takes a string of equal length rows separated by newlines, and returns a string in the same format.  May throw an exception on invalid input.

Previous solution:

```
def h(a):
 i=a.find('+');q=[i];w=a.find('\n')+1;z=[*a]
 while q:
  i=q.pop();c=a[i];k=-5
  for p,j in enumerate((i+1,i-1,i+w,i-w)):
   r='++-|='[p>1::2]
   if 0<=j<len(a)and a[i]in r and a[j]in r:
    k+=1<<p;q+=[j][:z[j]<'─']
  z[i]='│'if c>'='else'─═'[a[i]>'-']if c>'+'else"┌╒┐╕┬╤@@└╘┘╛┴╧##├╞┤╡┼╪$$"['='in a[abs(i-1):i+2]::2][k]
 return''.join(z)
```

Ungolfed version:

```
def h(a):
    i = a.find('+')         # find index of first '+'. It is first node
    q = [i]                 # in the queue of indexes to convert to unicode
    w = a.find('\n')+1      # width of the table
    z = [*a]                # strings are immutable, so copy it to a list

    while q:                # while the queue isn't empty
        i=q.pop()           # get the next index to process
        c=a[i]              # and the associated character

        k=-5                # 'k' is the index into the unicode string, U.  The way they
                            # are encoded, the first unicode value is at index 5. 

                 # directions  E   W   S   N
        for p,j in enumerate((i+1,i-1,i+w,i-w)):  # j is the index of an adjacent cell

            # r='++-|='[p>1::2] is equivalent to:
            if p > 1:
                r = '+|'    # compatible symbols for vertical connections
            else:
                r = '+-='   # compatible symbols for horizontal connections

            # if adjacent cell index is valid and the characters are compatible
            if 0 <= j < len(a) and a[i] in r and a[j] in r:
                k += 1<<p                 # update the unicode symbol index

                # q += [j][:z[j]<'─'] is equivalent to:
                if z[j] < '-':            # if the adjacent cell hasn't been converted already
                    q.append(j)           #  append it's index to the queue

            if c > '=':
                z[i] = '│'                # replace a '|' with a '│'

            elif c > '+':
                z[i] = '─═'[a[i]>'-']     # replace a '-' or '=' with '─' or '═' respectively 

            else:                                      # it's a '+'
                U = "┌╒┐╕┬╤@@└╘┘╛┴╧##├╞┤╡┼╪$$"         # even indexes are single horizontal line, 
                                                       # double horizontal lines are at odd indexes

                z[i] = U['='in a[abs(i-1):i+2]::2][k]  # '='in a[abs(i-1):i+2] is true if there is an '=' to the left or right
                                                       # so this selects the odd chars from U
                                                       #  then [k] selects the correct char

 return''.join(z)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>914</s> <s>898</s> <s>827</s> <s>823</s> <s>594</s> <s>587</s> <s>569</s> <s>540</s> 469 bytes

Edit: significantly changed strategy, now making a bitfield of neighbors (similar to dead-possum's answer). I've left the earlier version below.

```python
H='─│═-|=└╘++++┌╒├╞++┘╛++┴╧┐╕┤╡┬╤┼╪'
def n(l):
 def j(r,c,t=0):O=(0,r-1,c),(1,r,c+1),(2,r+1,c),(3,r,c-1);v=f(r,c);b=t|any(f(Y,X)=='='for i,Y,X in O);l[r][c]={'+':H[b+2*sum((f(Y,X)in H)<<x for x,Y,X in O)],**dict(zip(H[3:6],H))}.get(v,v);[f(Y,X)!=';'and v in'+++-|='[i%2::2]and j(Y,X,v=='=')for i,Y,X in O]
 for i,I in enumerate(l):
  if'+'in I:f=lambda r,c:l[r][c]if len(l)>r>=0and 0<=c<len(l[r])else';';j(i,I.index('+'));break
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVLBattAED1bX7E2FO1mJWPJIVDZm7NzyiXQFtcHRVol665lI22M06pQeu4hFAkCLYVCoFB67LFfsz/izkqOYyftwrA7b97MvBlpca0u52l/vR4xW5cfdPlRVzduwXRZ6uqWwtHlJ1191uVXXX0z3q2uvpj7t65@6PJGV5Uu73T1XZe/dHWnyz@6@mlbMU9QiiUJLGSeU5w5kaNYjwSnDPeczPWciDjYcwCnHrx8J6MN1jeY65HBkiUmjQzOmSrC9Bon@JXzkjBmMzuZZ0g44CKRolMykONsMo4m7J1N7WA0Pqf@QX41w5sU4IzIcLhCJm31kDZxDg5iESn8VizwaNwPjibOiJD33Quu8NJZksG4KdBm9sAO0xgtIdGGrcCK7LF45geBPzH41NCcZa2N7IubWKgBTozL06sZz0LFm@UgkYBiwE@ChMlwdh6HCGYONvOIBElu9nicHbOeadQbsmhYY8AgXOYclA2mGMp3RRrzFYZ6BHaW8fDNuv4OkYdz6NXKuLrKUjSWIld4VatcGUl5N19IobD9OrXJpEnxa3mbFBPoTucixfbm3smWpM5Qq6aJRKxpaLWM7m3XumLD5NDeUJXHUKfTodSiFG7Lap35NYLMoYyxrVk1VCAPzAfro8JC1HXdR6yG8ZS1a9YmauwQ7Oh/LLe/MWC4z2uW6bLLMrJbCEbpN6O4Tw61ClA@4lLO6Yt5JuO2GcQylR4dwzy7FDkSOZ1do0RkuQJmQV2KonnMi4u5TGAvLm3A6DKUsuDpBW834L@6N3tVh3vy6JZ6HxcPezcd3M3C4Q3H2sHrgZXw7@tBKQhY29AiE6nC8DMoj5Ad98zfc1V/3z3cd8Ujdz@50wG3@YvWfwE)

Input is in the form of a list of lists of characters, which is modified in place. Recurses from the first + that it finds.

```python
x=range
C='┌┐└┘','╒╕╘╛'
D='┬┤┴├','╤╡╧╞'
A='┼╪'
H,V,T='─│═'
J={'-':H,'|':V,'=':T}
K=C[1]+D[1]+A[1]+'='+T
E=('+|','+-=')*2
F=['+|'+V,'+-='+H+T]*2
O=(0,-1,0),(1,0,1),(2,1,0),(3,0,-1)
for i in x(4):
 for j in{0,1,2,3}-{i}:F[i+2&3]+=D[0][j]+D[1][j]
 h=C[0][i]+C[1][i];F[i&2]+=h;F[3-2*(i&1)]+=h
def n(l):
 for i,I in enumerate(l):
  if'+'in I:r=i;c=I.index('+');break
 else:return l
 def f(r,c):
  try:assert c>=0 and r>=0;return l[r][c]
  except:return'\0'
 def j(r,c):
  v=f(r,c)
  l[r][c]=J.get(v,v)
  if v=='+':
   X=[f(r+Y,c+X)for i,Y,X in O];B=any(x in K for x in X);X=[X[x]in F[x]for x in x(4)];L=sum(X)
   if L in(2,3,4):l[r][c]=D[B][X.index(False)]if L==3 else C[B][X[0]*2+X[3]]if L==2 else A[B]
  for i,Y,X in O:
   if v in E[i]and f(r+Y,c+X)in E[i]:j(r+Y,c+X)
 j(r,c);return l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVRPa9swFD9Xn0LLobIruSR2GcxBg65dabtCL6FL8XzIHKVR5jrFVktKUxg77zCGDYONwaAwGDvuuE@jL5I92U6adJvgWXrv99P7K3xxrYbjxJvNJjztJWcC7XCi8/c6/6DzXOefCCO6@KiLQhefdPGZoF2D/9T5nc5/6fxLid/p4psuvuviK0HbBv@tix8E7bMT1jHqW52/08UHgg75DXGIv8/IlPgnjHDid27RC74TtEK6az7b5gN22kHPuUXoFAJQhxN7w0V7PDAGelKZ6D7thGA@5laTOS3WtJkFX9aC3WWV7jED2WgwTrHEMsETa8v2ETb6CPQboDOXebfOjbz19wJJ3XUvpHw3aIbBqMoJdoSHkCOYZEhNrrC3gbzuAnUIJ89xNyy53rKNjvpigBMrnseR7MBEFsnluUh7SlQIlgNCCdgP/JTLdsQPNmXSFxOomdjt16novUFYxJnwU6Eu0wTHCBvHAytlUelApdd@L8tEqnD0lDdxL@njFA7t@YUgDYMIcsdiEokLVTsir5qkcjVauLrilVs41rf44eaZUNYVu7LLXIECHSeGjLs8ADo9ZRHt2lWFp6xrajwO2894L7m2JkZ7UZZfHrt2G251g0kIyh5sC8QMJGwf8ezy3OqaWCbYESAwQ4/BsOYJ7QbPwqBbN2mvB52xQ0Pl3Cv7hHdKAkxpw6XdwAtr1K3QbUDB@2q6fh3vymjPYaqmh/e11UZ/tLCgummLHs/KaUctK4NGrtXWIJaZsib2oshsM7uIpbLIq4TYYXXFLd/B2nwoCdkcjaFqUu9Lt2O7vKEmK0HAQWKVge0aFxDUEFSL40ajQSmiFHaE1jpuacFmUc75QlBpmuIWiAvi4SnC1HGcB6yK8TdrWVCNGtkCefw/luPVAgznSckyUZZZJu01DKV4VSnOX4uiKWS@L@J4TF@O07j/yBSCjKcHyzA7Q5lhmdHzazyQaaaAOaUOxdG4L6Zn43gAfXFoZYyGvTieCvgZPqqM/4pe9VVtraRHF9Q5Lu/7biI4dcPhDAst2cuClXTn/sAVAGgBXaQyURY8AdWCcd@rHXdFVd6qurWqygfq6uVGA9TqFc3@AA)

Here's the closest thing I have to an ungolfed version:

```python
def tr(s):
    t='┌┐└┘','╒╕╘╛'
    t2='┬┤┴├','╤╡╧╞'
    A = '┼','╪'
    H,V,T = '─│═'
    Th = ''.join(x[1]for x in (t,t2,A))+'='+T
    ps = ['+|'+V, '+-='+H+T, '+|'+V, '+-='+H+T]
    ps2 = ('+|', '+-=')*2
    for i in range(4):
        for j in {0,1,2,3}-{i}:
            ps[(i+2)%4] += t2[0][j]+t2[1][j]
        h=t[0][i] + t[1][i]
        ps[i & 2] += h
        ps[3 - 2 * (i & 1)] += h

    l = [list(x) for x in s.split('\n')]
    r = 0
    for i,I in enumerate(l):
        if'+'in I:
            r=i;c=I.index('+')
            break
    def g(r,c): return l[r][c]
    def G(r,c):
        if r >= 0 and r < len(l) and c >= 0 and c < len(l[r]):
            return g(r,c)
        return '\0'
    def process(r,c):
        v = g(r,c)
        if v == '-': l[r][c] = H
        elif v == '|': l[r][c] = V
        elif v == '=': l[r][c] = T
        elif v == '+':
            all=[G(r-1,c),G(r,c+1),G(r+1,c),G(r,c-1)]
            bold=any(x in Th for x in all)
            for i in range(4):all[i] = all[i] in ps[i]
            N,E,S,W=all
            tt=sum(all)
            if tt == 3:
                l[r][c]=t2[bold][all.index(False)]
            elif tt == 2:
                l[r][c]=t[bold][N*2+W]
            elif tt == 4:
                l[r][c]=A[bold]
            else: return
        for i,(dy,dx) in enumerate(((-1,0),(0,1),(1,0),(0,-1))):
            if v in ps2[i] and G(r+dy,c+dx) in ps2[i]:
                process(r+dy,c+dx)
    process(r,c)
    return l
```

Comment: Minor improvements to save 9 bytes (down to 814)  https://bit.ly/2NOu7HF

Comment: Few more for another 9 bytes (805 bytes now) https://bit.ly/2pYom0x

Comment: Down to 763: https://bit.ly/2OxErsJ

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <s>311</s> 307 bytes

```
X=>(O=[...X],P=(I,j=0,_=0)=>!P[I]&&(P[I]=1,['-─1','|│','=═1'].map(([a,b,n=X.indexOf('\n')+1])=>[-n,+n].map(n=>{for(i=I;X[i+=n]==a;)O[i]=b
if(X[i]=='+')j|=[1,2,4,8,I-i>1&&17,i-I>1&&18][_],P(i)
_++})),O[I]='┘└┴ ┐┌┬ ┤├┼     ╛╘╧ ╕╒╤ ╡╞╪'[j-5]),P(X.indexOf`+`),O.join``)
```

```js
f=
X=>(W=X.indexOf('\n')+1,O=[...X],P=(I,j=0,_=0)=>!P[I]&&(P[I]=1,['-─1','|│','=═1'].map(([a,b,n=W])=>[-n,+n].map(n=>{for(i=I;X[i+=n]==a;O[i]=b);if(X[i]=='+')j|=[1,2,4,8,I-i>1&&17,i-I>1&&18][_],P(i);_++})),O[I]='┘└┴ ┐┌┬ ┤├┼     ╛╘╧ ╕╒╤ ╡╞╪'[j-5]),P(X.indexOf`+`),O.join``)


console.log(
f(
`+------------------+
|   Hello+World!   |
+==================+
| This is+my first |
|+-+ code|golf  +-+|
|+-+chall|enge! +-+|
+------------------+`
))

console.log(
f(
`     +===+===+===+
     | 1 | 2 | 3 |
 +---+===+===+===+
 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
 +---+---+---+---+
 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 6 |
 +---+---+---+---+
 |-3 |-3 |-6 |-9 |
 +===+---+---+---+`
))

console.log(
f(
`+-----+
+-----+`))

console.log(
f(
`++++
++++
++++`))
```

### Explanation

Starting at the first found `+` junction, the program attempts to find paths to other junctions in every direction, performing replacements as it goes. It stores the found directions and the "double-bordered" state in a bitmap, which then determines the appropriate junction character.

```
// Take an input string X
f = X => {
    // Copy the input string into an array so characters can be overwritten and eventually output
    O = [...X]

    // Define a function that processes a junction ("+" symbol) at index I in the input string X:
    P = I => {
        // Make a bitmap to keep track of the direction coming out of the junction and double borders
        // Bits from right to left: west, east, north, south, double border
        // E.g. a double-bordered south/east junction corresponds to the binary number 11010 ("╒")
        let j = 0

        // A counter
        let _ = 0

        // Ensure this junction hasn't already been processed
        if(!P[I]){
            P[I] = 1,

            // We'll walk away from the junction in each of the four directions, then west and east again to check for double borders
            // i.e. walk along `a`, replace with `b`, move index `i` by `n`
            // 1st pass: walk along "-", replace with "─", move index by 1
            // 2nd pass: walk along "|", replace with "│", move index by the width of the input (plus 1 for the newline) to traverse vertically
            // 3rd pass: walk along "=", replace with "═", move index by 1
            ['-─1','|│','=═1'].map(([a, b, n = X.indexOf('\n') + 1])=>
                // We'll walk in the negative and positive directions for each pass
                [-n,+n].map(n=>{
                    // Start the walk
                    i=I
                    // Keep walking (incrementing by n) as long as we're on a "path" character, "a"
                    while(i += n, X[i] == a)
                        // Replace the corresponding character in the output with "b"
                        O[i] = b

                    // Upon reaching another junction at index i:
                    if(X[i] == '+'){
                        // OR the bitmap according to the direction we walked
                        j |= [
                            // Pass 1: Horizontal
                            1, // west
                            2, // east

                            // Pass 2: Vertical
                            4, // north
                            8, // south

                            // Pass 3: Double Horizontal (only if we've walked more than 1 step)
                            I-i > 1 && 17, // west, double border
                            i-I > 1 && 18 // east, double border
                        ][_]

                        // Process the junction we walked to
                        P(i)
                    }
                    _++
                })
            )

            // Finally, replace the "+" with a proper junction character based on the bitmap value
            O[I] = '     ┘└┴ ┐┌┬ ┤├┼     ╛╘╧ ╕╒╤ ╡╞╪'[j]
        }
    }

    // Process the first junction to kick off the recursion
    P(X.indexOf`+`)

    // Return our modified character array as a joined string
    return O.join``
}
```

Comment: Fixed - I must have looked at the character count and not the byte count.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 599 bytes

I'm not really good at golfing in Python 3, but (to my shame) I couldn't get normal output of UTF-8 chars in Python 2. So here we are.

I guess the only interesting trick here is deciding of `+` tranformation.
I've encoded all possible variants with 4-bit adresses. Each bit of adress resembles connection to neightbour cell. So 0 - no connection and 1 - connection.
`1111` is `┼`
`0011` is `┐`
etc
Some configurations of connections are invalid and replaced with dummy values: `'012┐45┌┬8┘0┤└┴├┼'`

If any neightbour cell contains `=`, second list will be used with doubled lines.

```
['012┐45┌┬8┘0┤└┴├┼','012╕45╒╤8╛0╡╘╧╞╪']['='in r]
```

Adress is combined here.

```
r=''.join([str(int(V(y,x)))+W(y,x)for y,x in[(Y-1,X),(Y,X+1),(Y+1,X),(Y,X-1)]])
```

`r` contains string lenght 8, where every two chars are 1/0 and actuals neightbour char.
For example: `1+0y1-1|`.
This is used to choose list of substitutions as shown before. And then contracted to adress: `int(r[0::2],2)`

This lambda used to verify that cell coordinates are valid and cell's char is one of '+-|='

```
V=lambda y,x:~0<x<len(I[0])and~0<y<len(I)and I[y][x]in'+-|='
```

This lambda used to receive char from cell. Returns `' '` if coordinates are invalid. (definately can be golfed away)

```
W=lambda y,x:V(y,x)and I[y][x]or' '
```

Conditions for recursion. Might be golfable too.

```
if Z in'+-=':F(Y,X+1);F(Y,X-1)
if Z in'+|':F(Y-1,X);F(Y+1,X)
```

---

```python
I=eval(input())
J=[i[:]for i in I]
V=lambda y,x:~0<x<len(I[0])and~0<y<len(I)and I[y][x]in'+-|='
W=lambda y,x:V(y,x)and I[y][x]or' '
def F(Y,X):
 if V(Y,X)and I[Y][X]==J[Y][X]:
  Z=I[Y][X]
  if','>Z:
   r=''.join([str(int(V(y,x)))+W(y,x)for y,x in[(Y-1,X),(Y,X+1),(Y+1,X),(Y,X-1)]])
   J[Y][X]=['012┐45┌┬8┘0┤└┴├┼','012╕45╒╤8╛0╡╘╧╞╪']['='in r][int(r[0::2],2)]
  else:J[Y][X]=dict(zip('|-=','│─═'))[Z]
  if Z in'+-=':F(Y,X+1);F(Y,X-1)
  if Z in'+|':F(Y-1,X);F(Y+1,X)
e=enumerate
F(*[(y,x)for y,r in e(I)for x,c in e(r)if'+'==c][0])
for r in J:print(''.join(r))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xVVPa9swFL/7U2i9yKrtkaRd6Lxqx7D0PPonQofMVlaP1AmqO5Jhxth5hzJsKGwMBoXB2HHHfRp9kUySUyVNlS4tDbv8rPdP7/2enuThODsepFuTaBAzgMHGxsakjdnbbt9N0uFZ5iLk7GGSkJD2BhwkIElBmzr7uN89eRV3wdgfhe9ru6PdPkvdNqlR1E1jqRhXCiWBNhlTMqJJCr0gx9A5mA/edyXOuw04BNCJWQ@03CP/EIUOSHpgX68rtyNKDinGe9VC2kEHT7VynfSgD593lBpwDOHjN4MkdclpxiWjzK3yIeQd6IUiJb@SFnGPgrrM4atMXl19PSMHdUQpUltOs2ICa/WGKM63n4jikyh@7YjioiaKS1EUovgtiq@i@CMLUU5lKZ3Kz6K83BHll5oov4vyQpQ/RPlNlD8hJRBD2VZOiSqQk1oYNqjfQIoN65@y8CpnnESZ@y4ZujAPsNxcFB9F8UGU5xAh0qnIgw7QjcYwbE2ZPGtNKcw75NquGSu7puowzNKzE8a7GXNa7iaZaxFXJ8/kiSpx5EeVyJFstwcxjqg6e0cZtedeOOSKzVX/OUITOVuOw0YsAq6etk3QRBNCZLwPYLA28CD1AYG5WoPr8EIBU9A3MKhiJBwYkRtrrOCRZau8yqID8drgBpeXCo4VJApOjWEm6pJOFIyNtWdcuPHLFrnkJjowK22PTGNi00Dt/NoY@ibLrEULW92SJTKsutcPJzf5UpOPXT8Se5b1zxh1bo6yZ53Eh3PKF2dwhZH0rBP1ME66B8ByO4DFH99NpytYuveMet2ia1h0W4t9ApY@Bw9Z9@01rqnue@tsdTdWrHHbomv@n7qDxZ7dpmtadE@X1207//vXbXtA/vVT8@74Pi29P7ZXOljl4i0EzsOdAld4S2eM52PtryWlfwE)